# Creating a temporary table with 100000 random values?

Tags: mysql

How can I create a temporary table and with one column and 100000 rows and fill each of the rows with a unique random value like 473824hdhdas?

Thanks!

Comment: you start by writing some code. mysql can generate randoms with rand(), but getting non-numeric values in there isn't worth the trouble of doing it in mysql. write some client-side code (e.g. php) to do it for you.

Comment: `insert into foo (bar) select rand() from somethingwith100000rows;` but then, you'll want a stored function that returns the kind of random you want...  Is it fixed or variable length?  We don't know the parameters.  I don't think you should need external code just for a string of letters/numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')
FROM 
  (SELECT
    (two_1.id + two_2.id + two_4.id + 
    two_8.id + two_16.id) AS id
   FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS id) AS two_1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 id) AS two_2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 4 id) AS two_4
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 8 id) AS two_8
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 16 id) AS two_16
   ) AS init
-- set your limit to needed count of rows
LIMIT 100000
```

-it [will generate](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bad6e/26) alphanumeric unique set of rows. To create table, just use the [corresponding syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Update. Since there are some doubts about hex-generated values, just modify:

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(
     CONV(SUBSTR(uuid, 1, 8), 16, 36),
     CONV(SUBSTR(uuid, 9, 8), 16, 36),
     CONV(SUBSTR(uuid, 17, 8), 16, 36),
     CONV(SUBSTR(uuid, 25, 8), 16, 36)
   ) as rnd
FROM 
  (SELECT
    REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '') AS uuid,
    (two_1.id + two_2.id + two_4.id + 
    two_8.id + two_16.id) AS id
   FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS id) AS two_1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 id) AS two_2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 4 id) AS two_4
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 8 id) AS two_8
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 16 id) AS two_16
   ) AS init
LIMIT 100000
```

-now [all 36 letters](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bad6e/31): `0-9`, `A-Z`

Comment: not sure if this really qualifies as random? Seems more like `ONE` random value and then `x` permutations/variations of that.

Comment: That's pretty slick.  I think asker will want something that generates letters outside hexadecimal though.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste well the full join would be 4 billion values, so getting a random sample of that would be somewhat random.

Comment: Well, OP didn't mentionet neither anything about restrictions nor anything about use-case. But in any case this is useful at least to know how to generate desired rows count. And no - it isn't permutation. It's cross join

Comment: like: `473824hdhdas` - Obviously that's not a hex number.  Though I agree a sample size of one with no description is pretty vague.

Comment: It isn't But such restriction isn't mentioned.

Comment: @AlmaDo You're obviously very bright.  Why do you think code that **cant** generate the **only** example would be acceptable?

Comment: @AlmaDo totally true, OP did not mention anything about that, it is just that I associated `random values` with `random values that possibly can vary on any digit`, that was not mentioned, but I thought it was worth mentioning ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I don't follow.  His example (unless I misread) could give random on every single hex digit returned (he didn't rand() sort it, but not sure if that'd run fast enough).  Also, the value is unique in the rowset, which was requested.  Oh wait, I keep thinking he's returning a hex value of the number he generated in the JOINs.

Comment: @ebyrob ok, ok. I've updated.

Comment: @AlmaDo base 36 :-)  Very nice.  Now I'm quibbling, but why not pull data from `Id` and just order by `RAND()`?  Or are we talking universe heat-death here for the time to run?

Comment: when I run the last fiddle I always get 20 rows of `3W5E11264SGSF`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste fixed (int overflow)

Comment: @ebyrob because to produce good unique random set we'll need - yes, select _all 4 billions_, then do `ORDER BY RAND()` (weird), then apply LIMIT. pretty bad. If only to do that with id from 1..LIMIT - there will be very weak random row

Comment: @AlmaDo I been hacked!! This only returns 32 rows (5 bits) not 4 billion rows (32 bits).  Query would need to have 32 joins in it (not 5) to get to 32 bits...